# Is there a way to take a folder from an EC2 instance and then every day send its content to a bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So I have this program, but I want to send the daily status of it into my s3 bucket.
Sometimes/frequently I terminate my EC2 instance and I want to be able to save the content on a folder in my EC2 server and send it to a bucket where it can be saved. Is there a way to do this automatically like every day and/or manually?
I SSH with a Linux command line via Amazon Linux 2 Free Tier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of the following:

- IAM role on the EC2 instance that allows access to the S3 bucket
- awscli to perform the folder sync to S3 (`aws s3 sync folder s3://bucket/folder`)
- cron on Linux to run the aforementioned awscli on a schedule

Obviously you can also run awscli to sync manually any time you want.